# LWJGL Native folder doesn't have folders

Tags: java, macos, lwjgl

I am using eclipse to program on my mac using LWJGL 3. Everything is good according to the tutorial except the natives folder doesn't have the Macosx, Window, or linux folders. i downloaded all three types and the same thing happened every time. can you help me!

The native folder looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is intentional. The native folder structure has changed in LWJGL3 and so all native files for all platforms are in a single folder. Just set `java.library.path` to this folder and LWJGL will automatically load the correct files for your platform.

The [rationale for the change](http://blog.lwjgl.org/lwjgl-3-0a-released/):

> Native binaries for all OSes and architectures now live in the **same directory**. The previous structure, with different subdirectories for each OS/arch, was causing trouble with popular application launchers and tools that create/extract JARs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share, its better to start your `.jar` file where your natives are

```
|- thatsyour.jar
|- lwjgl.dll
|- and all the others
```

Comment: @Chthonic Project, im sorry, im from Germany... thanks for spellchecking^^